# Gulp: useref multiple PHP files

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, gulp

I recently developed a second page on one of my websites which I put in my projects folder so it can be accessed like "www.mysite.com/projects"  My directory looks like this:

```
|js
|css
|projects - has index.php 
|img
index.php
mailer.php
```

My Gulp file:

```
I used Gulp useref like this:
gulp.task('useref', function(){
  return gulp.src('app/*.php')
    .pipe(useref())
        // Minifies only if it's a JavaScript file
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    // Minifies only if it's a CSS file
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))

});
```

But when I execute the command to run `useref`, it doesn't useref the php file in projects or move the folder over to my dist folder.  I tried doing it like  `return gulp.src('app/**/*.php')` but that doesn't work either.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have something backwards here. You have to pipe into useref your index file. Meaning that your source is not every php file in your app, but

```
gulp.src('your_Path/index.html')
```

Then, you have to tell useref where to look for all the files referenced in index.html with:

```
.pipe(useref({
    searchPath: 'app/' // I'm guessing this is the path
}))
```

Also, you only need one *dest* in this case. Which makes your task:

```
gulp.task('useref', function(){

  return gulp.src('your_Path/index.html') // Check this path
     .pipe(useref({
         searchPath: 'app/' // Check this path
     }))
    // Minifies only if it's a JavaScript file
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
    // Minifies only if it's a CSS file
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))

});
```